# Sync method call for a requireJS module

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, synchronization, oracle-jet

I am trying to build a navigation bar using Oracle Jet components, since I am concerned about the modularity of my code, I am feeding my navbar with the needed information from another module that I load using requireJS. When executed I get this error `Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return pages }"
Message: pages is not defined`

My first guess (after using breakpoints) is that the binding is done before my variable *pages* gets the appropriate data. If it is the case, how can I make sure that the navbar prints only after my variable is properly initialized, if it is not, what am I doing wrong?

here's my code:

**the template**

```
<div id="topbar">
<div class="oj-sm-condense" data-bind="ojComponent:{
                component: 'ojNavigationList',
                selection: currentPage,
                navigationLevel: 'application',
                edge: 'top'}" >

    <ul id="pills" >
     <!-- ko foreach: pages -->
     <li data-bind="attr:{id:id}">
        <a data-bind="attr:{href:url}">
            <p data-bind="text:label"></p>
        </a>
    </li> 
     <!-- /ko-->
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**the JS for the template**

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'ojs/ojnavigationlist'
], function (oj, ko) {

function homeContentViewModel(data) {

    var self = this;
    require(['banner/' + data],  function (pages) {
        self.pages=pages;
    });
}
return homeContentViewModel;
});
```

**The data Module**

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'ojs/ojnavigationlist'
], function (oj, ko) {

    this.currentPage=ko.observable('Page1');
    var self = this;
    var pages = [
    {id: "id1", label:"Page1", url: "#"},
    {id: "id2", label:"Page2", url: "#"},
    {id: "id3", label:"Page3", url: "#"},
    {id: "id4", label:"Page4", url: "#"},
    {id: "id5", label:"Page5", url: "#"},
    {id: "id6", label:"Page6", url: "#"},
    ];  

    return pages;
});
```

**The index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>navbar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/libs/oj/v2.0.1/alta/oj-alta-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div data-bind="ojModule: {name: 'path/to/template', params: 'dataModuleName'}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'ojs/ojnavigationlist'
], function (oj, ko) {

function homeContentViewModel(data) {

    var self = this;
    self.pages = ko.observableArray();
    require(['banner/' + data],  function (pages) {
        self.pages(pages);
    });
}
return homeContentViewModel;
})
```

define pages as an empty observable array before the require call